# Python: array values somehow getting changed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In my code, I have loaded data to an array. While looping over the array, everytime the `else` is executed, the array values of the `amat` array get changed (only for those i's where the loop is executed).

That is, `amat[i]` before the for loop does not equal `amat[i]` after the for loop, for those i's where the `else` statement is executed.

Here's my code snippet.

```
amat = np.loadtxt(infl)
for i,yentry in enumerate(amat):
    depth = yentry[0]
    if depth < dhigh:
        if depth >= dlow:
            if bint == 1:
                mindepth = dlow
            matline += yentry
            count += 1
    else:
        avgmat = matline / float(count)
        bavg[bint,:] = avgmat
        depthfix = round((dlow + dhigh)/2,1)
        bavg[bint,0] = depthfix
        stringlist.append((' '.join(['%10.6f ']*len(avgmat))+'\n') % tuple(avgmat))
        avgmat = yentry
        matline = yentry
        bint += 1
        count = 1
        dlow = dhigh
        dhigh += step
```

What could be causing this? As you can see, I have no statements which should affect the value of amat. Yet, something is obviously going on...

I know it's hard to diagnose without the full code, but can anyone think of any issues that might be causing this? How can my array get modified without applying any operations to it?

Comment: Your code contains variables like `matline` and `avgmat` which don't seem to be defined before they're used.  Can you provide a self-contained, runnable example, including a small data sample, that actually demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define:

```
matline = yentry
```

inside the `else` block and after you do:

```
matline += yentry
```

it is actually changing one row of `amat`. Because `matline` is a reference to `yentry`, which is a reference to one row of `amat`.

To prevent this you could break the reference by creating a copy:

```
matline = yentry.copy()
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution fixed the problem. I don't fully understand though... The wrong values that `amat` is taking on are not contained within `amat`. It's as if it's getting changed with random numbers. Also, when do I have to use the `.copy()`? For example, should I say that `depth = yentry[0].copy()`? Should  I use `.copy()` whenever I do an operation when using the for loop variables?

Comment: @you only have to copy when there is a chain of references that must be broken. If `yentry` is a 1D array, when you do `yentry[0]` you already get a float number stored in a new variable, in a new place of memory... so you don't have to copy